# What does lvalue reference type mean

Tags: c++, types

Sec. 5.4/1 N3797 says:

> The result is an lvalue if T is an **lvalue reference type** or an rvalue
>   reference to function type and an xvalue if T is an rvalue reference
>   to object type.

What does it mean? I know what means lvalue expression. I've been trying to find an **lvalue reference type** definition int the Standard, but I can't. Could you possibly provide it?

Comment: For references in general, [see this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference). For  value-categories (sooner or later you'll get to them), [see this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category). Between those two I think you'll find what you need.

Comment: @T.C. Indeed, I just tried to find 'lvalue reference type'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term *lvalue reference* means a reference with one `&` in it, e.g.:

```
int &x = whatever;
int const &y = whatever;
```

In C++03, lvalue references were the only type of reference. In C++11, rvalue references were added, so the retronym *lvalue reference* was coined to mean non-rvalue references.

Lvalue references can bind to both lvalues and rvalues (with the restriction about non-const lvalue reference not being able to bind to a temporary object); rvalue references can only bind to rvalues.

Note: [universal references](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) may bind to lvalues or rvalues, and after binding they either behave like an lvalue reference, or like an rvalue reference.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 types of `lvalue reference` that are described in `The C++ Programming Language 4th Edition` as follow,

- A `non-const` `lvalue reference` refers to an object, to which the user of the reference can write.
- A `const` `lvalue reference` refers to a constant, which is immutable from the point of view of the user of the reference.

in addition,

- An `rvalue reference` refers to a temporary object, which the user of the reference can (and typically will) modify, assuming that the object will never be used again.